# Is it possible to build an application for the LinkedIn platform?

Tags: linkedin-api, social-media

Do you know if it's possible to build an application for the LinkedIn platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While LinkedIn has promised a public API for a very long time now, they have yet to deliver.

No, there is no **public** LinkedIn API yet.

IMO, their widgets (which there are only two of at the moment, which are very limited) don't count.

They say that they are open to being contacted with specific uses for their API and they may give access to parts as needed - but that is if they accept your ideas for integration. They have been very picky with this - and have not accepted my attempts to integrate with LinkedIn yet, they tell me I have to wait with everyone else, apparently my applications are not "high-profile" enough.

Sure, you'll find many Google results talking about their "promised" API, but they are empty promises and won't be of much help.

Comment: This answer is outdated, see my answer

Comment: You are correct, my answer is dated, posted 14 months ago. LinkedIn has (finally) launched a public API http://developer.linkedin.com

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they have API at http://developer.linkedin.com/index.jspa, allowing access to the profile, connections, messaging and more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Linkedin has an API:

- http://www.programmableweb.com/api/linkedin
- http://blog.linkedin.com/blog/2007/12/the-intelligent.html

So you could build an application that uses it.

**Update:** ([from second link](http://blog.linkedin.com/blog/2007/12/the-intelligent.html))

> We’ll be phasing all of this in over the coming months and to get involved with the Intelligent Application Platform either for APIs, widgets, or hosted applications, send us an e-mail to ***developers@linkedin.com*** telling us what you want to build and what you need to build it.

Since there are published Mashups using LinkedIn I would assume that means you can use the API even if the documentation isn't readily available.

As a tip, in the future include links to what you found that didn't work, so we know not to give it to you again.

I poked around a bit more and I found some [more on their widgets](http://www.linkedin.com/static?key=developers_widgets&trk=hb_ft_widgets) which appears to be the main focus of their API.